# Unable to transfer a call from one conference room to another using fs_cli

Tags: freeswitch, fusionpbx

I want to transfer a call that is present in one conference room to another conference room that is active. Currently, I'm using the uuid_transfer command in the fs_cli to transfer the call but the call gets disconnected. I tried other methods like putting the call on hold before using the uuid_transfer command but the results are the same.

To get the list of active conferences I use "conference xml_list" to fetch the conference name and the uuid of the call.
After this, I do "uuid_transfer 8cf501a0-8362-44d2-b50d-6837107ca0d9 conference_name". Here "8cf501a0-8362-44d2-b50d-6837107ca0d9" is the call UUID. The conference_name is 1100@fusionpbx_ip where 1100 is the extension of the conference room.

The uuid is taken from the room1 and the conference room in the command "uuid_transfer 8cf501a0-8362-44d2-b50d-6837107ca0d9 conference_name" is the room where I want to put the call. Also, the call should be removed from room 1 in this process. What am I doing wrong??

You can find the output of fs_cli when I use the uuid_transfer command [here](https://pastebin.pl/view/4b52496e)

Answer (score 0):

you can use conference transfer command instead doing it with uuid_transfer.

`conference <conf name> transfer <conference_name> <member id> [...<member id>]`